# (matplotlib) TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float -- all cells are floats

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, typeerror

I'm using matplotlib and pandas in shiny for Python, and getting a TypeError that I cannot find the root of. Since the line giving the error is `ax.imshow(heatmap_df)`, I asked the script to print out the contents of `heatmap_df` and the type of each cell...as you can see, they're all floats.

```
3.72749                  7.557595          1.644051        1.338884
3.249731                  8.012774          1.882097        1.007079
3.474328                  8.485558          1.923754        1.071482
3.07304                  8.552147          1.946201        0.994228
4.238958                  8.759728          1.989733        1.201516
3.216536                  8.052088          2.045725        1.176422
3.673571                  7.870499          2.046083        0.965033
4.502028                  9.406038          2.057907        1.181366
3.373406                  8.621299          2.070925        1.018748
3.453186                  8.899436          2.072196        1.188599
4.244796                   8.72604          2.120296         1.29829
4.41867                  8.024699           2.14317        1.085133
3.955012                 10.292628          2.191146        1.238102
3.64852                   9.12224          2.211133        0.989481
3.62534                  9.058587          2.240423        1.110407
3.074168                  8.606931          2.262263        0.917784
4.292992                  8.244456          2.323435        0.988629
4.464126                 10.343144          2.608713        1.166404
[<class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>]
[<class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>]
[<class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>]
[<class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>]
[<class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>]
[<class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>]
[<class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>]
[<class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>]
[<class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>]
[<class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>]
[<class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>]
[<class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>]
[<class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>]
[<class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>]
[<class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>]
[<class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>]
[<class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>]
[<class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/redacted/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/shiny/session/_session.py", line 1002, in output_obs
    message[output_name] = fn()
  File "/home/redacted/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/shiny/render/_render.py", line 214, in __call__
    return _utils.run_coro_sync(self._run())
  File "/home/redacted/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/shiny/_utils.py", line 178, in run_coro_sync
    coro.send(None)
  File "/home/redacted/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/shiny/render/_render.py", line 231, in _run
    x = await self._fn()
  File "/home/redacted/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/shiny/_utils.py", line 132, in fn_async
    return fn()
  File "/home/redacted/redacted/app.py", line 158, in person_level_heatmap
    ax.imshow(heatmap_df)
  File "/home/redacted/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/_api/deprecation.py", line 459, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/redacted/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1414, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
  File "/home/redacted/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5487, in imshow
    im.set_data(X)
  File "/home/redacted/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 706, in set_data
    raise TypeError("Image data of dtype {} cannot be converted to "
TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
```

Does anyone else see something I'm missing??

I've tried dropping additional arguments from the `ax.imshow(heatmap_df)` command (there were originally several there), and as shown above I've tried checking the type of every cell. I've referred back to other times that I've used this same method successfully and see nothing that I'm doing differently. I've looked around on StackOverflow, but even though I see the question asked many times I can't find an answer that helps.

I'm expecting the line to pass so I can continue to `ax.set_xticks`, etc. and everytually see a heatmap.

Edit: Since posting I've also tried upgrading matplotlib, converting the dataframe to a numpy array (see below), and commenting out all surrounding code.

```
heatmap_values = np.array(heatmap_df.values)
im = ax.imshow(heatmap_values)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also please put the full trace for the error message into the question.